# Get promise value inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in Javascript/NodeJS and I'm prefer practical work, I'm practicing by creating a bot discord with discord.js

The objective of this one is simply to display me the current value of the bitcoin in USD.

To get the value of BTC, I use the [coingecko-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coingecko-api) package.

However I'm blocked because although I can get the value of bitcoin, I can't do it when I'm in a loop without really understanding why.

main.js :

```js
var coin = require('./coingecko');

while(true) {
  coin.btc().then((value => console.log (value) )); // <= This show nothing

  // Other things
  ...
}
```

coingecko.js :

```js
const CoinGecko = require('coingecko-api');
const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

module.exports = {
    btc: async function btc() {
      let btc = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.fetch('bitcoin', {});

      return btc['data']['market_data']['current_price']['usd'];
    }
}
```

Any tips ? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Put your loop into an async function. Using `await` rather than `.then()` makes your looping logic much more straightforward.

```js
const coin = require('./coingecko');

/* declare the async function */
async function doLoop () {
  while(true) {
    const value = await coin.btc()
    console.log(value)
    // Other things
    ...
  }
}

/* invoke the async function from non-async context */
doLoop().catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure about the `["data"]` part?

When I test this API here I get this response: https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation

```
"market_data": {
"current_price": {
  "aed": 183098,
  "ars": 5097411,
  ...
  
  "uah": 1356629,
  "usd": 49850,
```

Also you can probably just do `btc.market_data.current_price.usd`